# Event created on delegate calendar via EWS is not visible to the delegated user

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices

I have 2 outlook users. Consider A & B. A has calendar (a) and B has calendar (b).

User B has given user A delegate access to calendar (b).

Now, using EWS API, when user A is creating event on calendar (b), the event is visible to user B only.

The same is not true for Microsoft Graph. If user A is creating event in calendar (b) then the event is visible to both the users.

I am not sure if it is the expected behavior or it's an issue.

Answer (score -1):

> Now, using EWS API, when user A is creating event on calendar (b), the event is visible to user B only.

What do you mean by Event is this an appointment or Meeting, if its a meeting you should be creating it in the organizers calendar A and inviting B, if its an appointment then if you want it to exist in both calendar then you will need to create it in both. Mailboxes are the boundaries so all your doing in both instance is creating an object in one store for it to be in the other store you need to either send and Invitation and have that accepted or create the object itself in both stores. What your seeing is the expected behavior (and what you would see if you just did it manually in Outlook or OWA)

Comment: My question is that if user A has delegate access to calendar (b), then user A should be able to view all events on calendar (b) either meetings or appointment.
But events(meetings or appointments) created via EWS API are not visible to user A. Whereas events created vis MS Graph API or Outlook webapp are visible to user A.
SO why this difference? Is this expected?

Comment: i thnk its a bug in EWS. Dont think microsoft support EWS anymore so they still havent fixed it in 2023. very annoying.